# exclude previously displayed products on product page

Tags: product-list, sorting

exclude previously displayed products while sorting random and navigating to next page

i m using

```
if($this->getCurrentOrder() != 'price'){
        if($this->getCurrentOrder() != 'created_at') {
            $this->_collection->getSelect()->order('rand()');
        }else{
            $this->_collection->setOrder($this->getCurrentOrder(), $this->getCurrentDirection());
    }
}else{
        $this->_collection->setOrder($this->getCurrentOrder(), $this->getCurrentDirection());
}
```

in toolbar.php to display random items in product page but the products keep repeating !!

Comment: got my answer ! just want to ask how to stop repeated products during pagination while appling random sort to the product list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**My thoughts on this approach**

First of all I want to say that I disagree with the random order of products in a shop.
It is bad for business because you cannot promote certain products if you want and is bad for user experience.
Here is an example.
I see a list of products and give the url to someone and say "look at the second and forth product on this list". They will see a totally different thing than I do.
Not to mention that the random sorting is slow. (well..I actually mentioned it)

**Possible solution**

but if you insist here is a possible solution.
You need to order the products by a ['seeded' random](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand) order and make sure the 'seed' is the same all through out the session.

Here is a possible approach. I haven't tested it, but I've used this kind of seeded random sorting for listing other entities.

```
if($this->getCurrentOrder() != 'price'){
    if($this->getCurrentOrder() != 'created_at') {
        //check if there is a seed in the session.
        $seed = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/session')->getListSeed();
        //if there is none, generated it and store it in the session
        if (!$seed) {
            $seed = time(); //can replace with custom logic if you want
            Mage::getSingleton('catalog/session')->setListSeed($seed);
        }
        //get a random number based on seed
        srand($seed);
        $rand = rand(0, 100);
        //pass the random number to the sorting.
        $this->_collection->getSelect()->order('rand('.$rand.')');
    }
    else{
        $this->_collection->setOrder($this->getCurrentOrder(), $this->getCurrentDirection());
    }
}
else {
        $this->_collection->setOrder($this->getCurrentOrder(), $this->getCurrentDirection());
}
```

Comment: "srand($seed);
        $rand = rand(0, 100); " is it $rand or srand how are you passing the value of $seed to rand as we are giving it a range 0 -100

Comment: @wittyvishwas. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.srand.php

Comment: working perfectly fine !! thanks @marius !!

Comment: I just came across this question and answer after a long time searching. I asked a duplicate of this. Could Marius post this answer on mine and I'll accept it? http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/63870/avoid-duplicates-in-random-collection

Comment: @kaska. Instead of duplicating my answer, wouldn't it be better if I close your question as duplicate of this?