# Avoid duplicates in random collection?

Tags: category, product-collection

My category list is showing a random list of products, but as one scrolls down the page it shows duplicates because it is just takes into account the first 20, as set by setPageSize.

```
$_productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
->getCollection()
->addAttributeToSort()
->addAttributeToSelect('*')
->addFieldToFilter(array(array('attribute'=>'visibility', 'neq'=>"1")))
->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1)
->addCategoryFilter($ccat->load()); 


$this->$_productCollection = 
Mage::getSingleton('cataloginventory/stock')
->addInStockFilterToCollection($_productCollection);


$_productCollection->setPageSize(20)->setCurPage(1);        
$_productCollection->getSelect()->order(new Zend_Db_Expr('RAND()'));
```

I tried creating a 'seen products' array but only the first twenty are added.

Is there any way I can randomise the collection but ensure each product shows once?

Comment: Why not get all in the query and print only 20 per time?

Comment: Ok, can you give me a bit more information on how I could do this?

Comment: The problem is that you are randomising the collection, so basically when you go to page 2, the product collection will reload again with a new random set of products that would probably have duplicates. You would need to look at some way to cache that collection and use it on the next page by just setting the current page.

Comment: Stuck with same problem. Did you get any solution man?

Comment: @Mohit I haven't been using Magento for a while but I got some help from this post https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/16982/17221

Answer (score 1):

To get random product, there is built in function. Add this block in **content area** of your custom `*.xml`.

```
block type="catalog/product_list_random" display_type="all_products" show_pager="1" products_per_page="5" products_count="10" template="path_to_your_list_file/custom_list.phtml
```

You can duplicate `catalog/product/list.phtml` file.

However, you are likely to get one error: see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24878900/call-to-a-member-function-getsortedchildren-on-a-non-object-in-magento-1-9).

I haven't tested this though.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I loaded this block instead of the default product_list but I still get duplicates when I scroll down the ajax scroll. Seems like what I'm trying to do might not be feasible. Thanks for your help.