# Reducing page load time on product collection / product collection usage options

Tags: category, product-list

I want to show the full product list from a category without pagination, however with ~500 simple products page loading is slow. Is there any way I can fetch the full collection and show sections at a time, reducing page load times?

Alternatively is there a way I can setPageSize(20) (or something), but save the full collection for use later in the list.phtml file?

Comment: Lazy Loading is good solution for such thing.

Comment: Try this extension http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/true-ajax-navigation-filter.html

Answer (score 1):

Loading 500 product will always slow down the server.

However you can trick the function to get the result.

You can load products on scroll, so that customer don't need to go to next page.

See this [link](http://turnkeye.com/blog/loading-products-with-ajax/).

If you using this function I would recommend to disable your pagination and count function from admin.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Actually I did have infinite ajax scroll on the site but because I needed to randomise products it showed duplicates. I will try your suggestion with the disabling, where in admin do I disable those?

Comment: You don't need to disable those, however since the counting will say **5 of 10 items** all the time(correct counting for first page) and pagination will still be visible. Which both doesn't make any sense. You can have a look my [implementation](http://www.digitalcinema.com.au/home-theatre-packages)

Comment: Ok, that's good to know, but I think my original problem remains. When page size is set, then each new 'page' of the scroll returns a random selection of products, which can include products already seen on the scroll. I'm trying to avoid duplicates, just show each product once, but in a random order each time.

Comment: Regarding your duplicate issue, you can open new thread, will require more info on that.

Comment: I have already :) but I couldn't make any progress.  http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/63870/avoid-duplicates-in-random-collection

Answer (score 0):

Implement full page caching, i.e.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/lesti-fpc-simple-fullpagecache.html

Comment: FPC isn't the best solution for that one, Lazy Loading would be better.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    $collection
        ->setPageSize(20)
        ->setCurPage($i)
        ->load();
```