# How can i fix duplicate product fetching on home page

Tags: magento-1.9, product

My theme is using this product loop to show chosen products on the home page. However, the results are acting weird - some products seem to cause it to stop before getting all products, hence only showing around 13 products instead of the desired 16 ones. When trying to load more, it loads some of the same products again.

I have tried contacting my theme developer, but they won't acknowledge the error, since they cant recreate it.

[Code on pastebin](http://pastebin.com/7LzPJZgU)

[Life demo of the error](http://tiny.cc/uity3x) - see featured products just below the banner on the frontpage

Comment: Did you try any debugging to pinpoint the error? It's quite some code and having the actual error or some idea where or for what to look would help

Comment: I have tried changing settings back and forth, trying to pinpoint what causes the error, but I haven't found an answer. Originally I thought it was some specific products that caused it, but upon investigating this doesn't seem to be the case, since it seems to stop at the same product number (currently 14) no matter which product this or the next is.
Any debugging suggestions are warmly welcome :-)

Comment: My guess is that it's to do with the random functions in your code. When the next page is reached, the 16 products are randomised again, and it doesn't save what appeared already, so repeats some

Comment: This is a solution I found worked when I wanted to randomise a product listing across pages: http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/16982/17221

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Do you have an idea why it doesn't load the correct number of products in the first place? That is my primary problem, but someone changed my title to not address it..

Comment: Looks like the page size is set to 14. Check any third party extension (e.g. in admin->system, on the left hand side, ajax infinite scroll or similar). There may be a setting for you to change this value to 16.@user2806026

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is not the case, because the number is not always 14. I have just changed sorting method, and now I get 15 products instead. For other sortings I might get 13 or even 12..

Comment: Sorry I don't know. If you inspect the Show More button on your site you can see there's an attribute `data-start = 15`. The class of that attr, `pdt-loadmore`, if you look at the jQuery at the bottom, `$uqtab` and the first part of the PHP file you inserted is based on a random number. So this is where I'd look if I could investigate it.@user2806026